# python os.system command line return value back to python

Tags: python, shell, command-line, arguments

I am calling a second python script that is written for the command line from within my script using

```
os.system('insert command line arguments here')
```

this works fine and runs the second script in the terminal. I would like this not to be output in the terminal and simply have access to the lists and variables that are being printed. Is this possible using os.system? Or, do I need to use something else?

Comment: it is best to import the module instead of running it as a script. See [Call python script with input with in a python script using subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the subprocess module and redirect its output through a pipe.

For example, to get the list of file in current directory.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.stdout.readlines())
```

More details here [Redirecting stdio from a command in os.system() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197509/redirecting-stdio-from-a-command-in-os-system-in-python)

**Edit**: if you are trying to pass arguments to subprocess.Popen each one gets its own set of quotes.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python','test.py','-b','-n'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And the doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thank-you for the answer. This works for 'ls' but when I try to run the python script i get this error: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. But my script is in the same directory as the second script I am trying to run. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried with two scripts in the same directory. Using proc = subprocess.Popen(['python','script.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) it worked perfectly. Make sure you are executing the python script in the correct directory

Comment: I wasn't splitting up the commands, I was writing 'python','script.py' as 'python script.py'. This fix the directory problem, bit now it is simply printing an empty list. I can confirm that the script works when I simply print it to the console.

Comment: Inside my test script, I just wrote print("something"). You can check it is working on your computer and adapt your script accordingly

Comment: I got it to work. I was trying to pass arguments without another set of quotes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the question answered if it is ok =)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to snoozeTime's answer you could use:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['ls'])
print(output)
```