# Python os.system call not writing stdout to the specified file

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell

I am trying to run some shell scripts from python, logging the stdout to a text file.

I tried to run the following dummy example. It works fine when I run the command from terminal, but writes an empty file when I call it from python.

Any idea why is that happening?

**Shell Script**: (~/shell_test)

```
echo "hello"
```

**Command Call**: (Works as expected from the terminal - shell_test_output.txt is created and "hello" is printed)

```
cd ~ && ./shell_test &>~/shell_test_output.txt
```

**Python:**  (shell_test_output.txt is written as empty file)

```
os.system("cd ~ && ./shell_test &>~/shell_test_output.txt")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting stdio from a command in os.system() in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197509/redirecting-stdio-from-a-command-in-os-system-in-python)

Comment: I try this. shell_test_output.txt is written as not empty. What is the return code of os.system("cd ~ && ./shell_test &>~/shell_test_output.txt")