# Storing output of os.system() in a variable

Tags: linux, python

I am generating a random word for my Hangman game, and hence want to generate a random word.

I am using the `/usr/share/dict/words` file and doing the following:

```
def word_select():
    import os
    word = os.system('head -$((${RANDOM} % `wc -l < /usr/share/dict/words` + 1)) /usr/share/dict/words | tail -1')
    return word
```

But when I check the value of word, it has the value 0 (Which is most probably the exit status of the command in round brackets). How do I store the word in my variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting stdio from a command in os.system() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197509/redirecting-stdio-from-a-command-in-os-system-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call shell commands from Python.
You can do everything in Python that shell commands can.
It's better to implement this either in pure Python or in pure Bash.

A simple implementation of your task is to read the entire contents of `/usr/share/dict/words` into a list, and then use the `random` module to select an item randomly.
The advantage of this solution is that it scans the file contents only once. Its drawback is reading the contents in memory. (Since that's less than 1MB, that should be a negligible concern on a modern system.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in Python, use the `subprocess` module instead.

Something like:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> myVariable = subprocess.check_output(["uptime"])
>>> myVariable
b' 20:48:53 up 42 min,  1 user,  load average: 0,21, 0,26, 0,26\n'
```

Official docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).