# What is a pythonic way of running a Python routine as another user (e.g. root)?

Tags: python, linux, sudo, privileges

In the spirit of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47858961/1672565) ("Don't call shell commands from Python. You can do everything in Python that shell commands can."), which is rather common advise given to many people, **how do I run a selected individual routine** (and ONLY this routine) **within a Python program as another user, e.g. root, in a pythonic** (and somewhat secure) **manner?**

For example, I have a routine like this in some code:

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

def kill_proc(pid, k_signal = signal.SIGINT, sudo = False):
    if sudo:
        subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'kill', '-%d' % k_signal, '%d' % pid]).wait()
    else:
        os.kill(pid, k_signal)
```

If I do not need to be root, I can just call `os.kill(pid, k_signal)` in this example. However, if I need super user privileges for sending a signal in my example, I must send the signal though a command in a subprocess. How could I use `os.kill` instead?

Comment: The answer you are quoting is a sweeping overgeneralisation. Don't give it much weight. What is a "shell command" anyway? If `cp` is one, why not `firefox`?

Comment: @n.m. I am aware of the overgeneralisation ;) Though, I have to admit that I am nevertheless interested to see whether there is an answer to this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a Python function as another user.

A Unix-like OS associates each process with a particular user. One cannot reassign a process to a different user unless the original owner was root to begin with. A Python function is not a process and cannot have its own user.

Comment: The least you must always do then is to spin up another process, which is somehow associated with the right user. Which begs the question whether there is a "pythonic abstraction" through e.g. modules like ``multiprocessing`` which would make this thing look like a normal function call ... *(I am well aware that this could easily become bizarre - firing up another Python interpreter process like ``multiprocessing`` does just for calling a small method like in my example.)*